# How do I remove a file in my root directory?

Tags: unix

I tried to create a directory `/data` as a mount point but that failed for other reasons, now I've got a weird file/data thing in my root directory that just won't die:

```
user@PC:~$ sudo ls /data
ls: cannot access /data: Transport endpoint is not connected

user@PC:~$ sudo rm -rf /data
rm: cannot remove ‘/data’: Is a directory
```

I initially created it using `mkdir` but if I browse to the file in ubuntu it looks like a file in the file browser. How do I get rid of this thing?

Comment: Try switching to root user and then use the "ls /data/" command

Comment: @dgsleeps what do you expect that to achieve? I'm already `sudo`ing

Comment: I've seen systems which do not respond to sudo command if not enough permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try unmounting then you should be able to delete it.

Then if that fails, and this is going to sound like a Windows solution but it might work, try rebooting and doing unmount/remount delete again.